# I want to generate qrcode of my localhost html page to display on android using ngrok

Tags: android, html, localhost, qr-code, ngrok

My localhost url is :file:///F:/First%20web%20app/signin.html

and my ngrok url is : http://a9ea5b40.ngrok.io

qr code used url is:http://a9ea5b40.ngrok.io/file:///F:/First%20web%20app/signin.html

Please give some suggestion ,so that i can access my localhost html page using my android phone by scanning the qr code...

i am getting error as

HTTP Requests
GET /favicon.ico      502 Bad Gateway
GET /file:///F:/First web app/signin.html 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: 502 bad gateway error

Comment: Hello! Please can you tell us what happens if you try to access `http://a9ea5b40.ngrok.io/signin.html` in your regular web browser?

Comment: Thanks brother...for your help....I got solution for this .......

Comment: Actually problem was ...I was not able to access that localhost website with Android phone and error was 502 bad gateway .... But then I got solution....

Answer (score -1):

Just follow steps...
First connect ur Android phone and laptop in same network....for this u can use hotspot or wifi....

After this run the localhost website in your laptop...

Open browser in your mobile phone.....

Type in address of your laptop in your Android phone and then type your website name .....and website will open..:)

Comment: He is using ngrok, so no need to be on the same network